# Integer solution of a linear equation with real coefficients

Tags: integer, equation

I am trying to figure out, if there is any way to solve an equation in the form

```
sum(w_i*x_i) = **w**^T**x** = s
```

[image]

Where the coefficients w_i are real, and the unknowns `x_i` are integers and the sum result s is real.

I am not interested in knowing all the possible solutions, but only the ones that delivers smaller solutions values and then investigate which one is meaningful. I have constraints on the unknown that they will not exceed a certain limit (e.g. `100`).

A trivial solution for this, to do nested for-loops for each `x_i` and save the solution each time the sum is equal the desired result. However, this is very costly and take too long when the number of unknows increases (Unknown may be in the range from `100` to `1000`).

I tried to understand the Diophantine equation and its extension for a linear equation system. In this case, I have one equation with n unknowns

How to optimize a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. For example, consider $n=1$ and $w_0=w_1=1$ and $s=0$. You get $x_0+x_1=0$, for which any integer $x_0$ is OK, as long as $x_1=-x_0$. What you have is a single equation with $n$ unknowns. The fact that $w_i$ are real and $x_i$ are integers might reduce the number of solutions, but it's not a generally the case